# Is 殷富 never used Kanji?

Tags: words

I want to say

> Human beings need not only health and wealth but also knowledge.

For the wealth, I chose 殷富{いんぷ} instead of 富{とみ}. When I said the following

> 健康{けんこう}や殷富{いんぷ}に限{かぎ}らず、人間{にんげん}は知識{ちしき}が必要{ひつよう}だ。

my teacher and other students did not recognize 殷富{いんぷ} and looked at me with strange faces as  淫婦{いんぷ} and  婬婦{いんぷ} were the only words available on their dictionaries.

## Questions

Is 殷富 never used or deprecated Kanji?

## Edit

My dictionary shows me the following.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't know the meaning and the reading of 殷富. I was able to guess the reading because a similar kanji is used in a not-so-rare compound [慇懃無礼【いんぎんぶれい】](http://jisho.org/search/%E6%85%87%E6%87%83%E7%84%A1%E7%A4%BC/) (殷 seems to be a variation of 慇, according to Wiktionary). But as for its meanings, I had no idea.

殷 is not in the Joyo kanji list. 殷 is the name of [an ancient Chinese dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty) (I barely remember learning it at middle high school), so this kanji may be well recognized by historians. Except for this, I don't know how to use this kanji at all.

婬婦 and 淫婦 are also rare, but it's much easier to guess their reading and meaning.

Simpler words like お金, 金銭, 富 all work fine.

Answer (score 5):

広辞苑 published by 岩波書店 carries the word, "殷富 (いんぶ)" and defines it as ”盛んで豊かなこと、富み栄えること –  rich and flourish.”

基礎中国語辞典（Basic Chinese Japanese Dictionary) published by 講談社 carries "殷富 (yinfu)" and defines it as “非常に富んでいる – being very rich.”

現代汉語詞典 (Modern Chinese Language Dictionary) published by 中国商務印書館 also carries "殷富" and defines it as “丰盛、丰富 ‐ flourishing and rich.”

It has nothing to do with the 殷 (Yin) Dynasty existed and prospered during 17 to 11 century before Christ, nor has any connection with "慇" of "慇懃" and "淫" of "淫婦, 淫行." They sound the same, but are totally different beasts. Don't mix up みそ with くそ!

I think 殷富 (いんぶ) is perhaps a loanword from Chinese. But I don’t know how current this word is both in Japan and in China.

This is the first time I heard of the word, “殷富,” and I’ve never read and heard it while I was studying Chinese language in a university in Beijing more than 20 years ago. Therefore I bet the currency of this word is very limited, and few Japanese and Chinese today would understand the meaning of the word and actually use it.

P.S.

After posting this answer, I recalled an oldish but pretty popular Japanese word, "殷賑 (いんしん)" which means "殷 - prosperous and 賑 - bustling."

It is used in the form of a set phrase, "殷賑 を極める - peak the prosperity," for examples:

新宿の街は新駅ビルの完成で殷賑を極めている - The prosperity of the town of Shinjuku is reachig its peak with the opening of the new station building.

戦前の両国は相撲の本場として、また歓楽街として殷賑を極めていた - Ryogoku was enjoying prosperity as the franchise of Sumo performances as well as an entertainment center in prewar Japan.

We used to make a fun of our colleague who is succesful and on the fast track by saying:

"最近奴さん, 殷賑を極めているようだね" - He seems to be enjoying all plain sailing these days.

The phrase, "殷賑 を極める," is much popular than "殷富" being used alone.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the 例文 on weblio: http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E6%AE%B7%E5%AF%8C

The references are all to historical place and people names, dating about 1000 years ago.  On the bright side, you'll be only one able to pronounce that difficult kanji on the tourist information board.